# php strtotime and timezones not behaving as expected

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Having unexpected results when using strtotime with timezone and calculations.  My PHP is set to UTC.  `strtotime("-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");` seems to be giving unexpected results.  I thought by providing the timezone it would be 'calculated IN' that timezone, but that doesn't appear to the case.

In my example I expect the results to be the same, regardless of PHP's default timezone because 'America/Chicago' is used in strtotime.  Instead it seems to take the current day (according to default timezone) and subtract days then calculate 00:00:00 in the timezone supplied.

Am I formatting this wrong?

I apologize for the messy code, but it is just an example demonstrating what I am talking about.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

echo convertTS(time(), "America/Chicago");

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$test = strtotime("-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");

echo $test;

echo "</br>";

echo convertTS($test, "America/Chicago");

echo "</br>";

$test = strtotime("-7 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");

echo $test;

echo "</br>";

echo convertTS($test, "America/Chicago");
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo "-----------------";
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

///now in America/Chicago

date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

echo convertTS(time(), "America/Chicago");

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$test = strtotime("-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");

echo $test;

echo "</br>";

echo convertTS($test, "America/Chicago");

echo "</br>";

$test = strtotime("-7 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");

echo $test;

echo "</br>";

echo convertTS($test, "America/Chicago");

function convertTS($timestamp, $timezone)
{
    if( empty($timestamp) )
    {
        return 'n/a';
    }
    else
    {
        //output the time
        $dt = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp);
        $dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
        return $dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
    }
}
```

result of the above at the time I ran it :

```
UTC

Fri, 01/04/19 @ 11:39:15 pm CST

1546149600
Sun, 12/30/18 @ 12:00:00 am CST
1546063200
Sat, 12/29/18 @ 12:00:00 am CST

-----------------

America/Chicago

Fri, 01/04/19 @ 11:39:15 pm CST

1546063200
Sat, 12/29/18 @ 12:00:00 am CST
1545976800
Fri, 12/28/18 @ 12:00:00 am CST
```

I made a sandbox to recreate this issue at all times [here](https://repl.it/repls/AromaticChillySolaris).  The difference being a timestamp is provided rather than using `time()` to show how the default timezone affects the results depending on time of the current day.

Comment: [Online sandbox](https://repl.it/repls/CanineRepentantStartups)

Comment: Thanks... I couldn't find a php sandbox would could be shared.  I edited the code a bit to recreate the issue at all times. https://repl.it/repls/AromaticChillySolaris

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's start by explaining few small things:

- Unix timestamps are always in UTC
- The timestamp you supplied **1546578000** in ISO 8601 format is: "**2019-01-04 05:00:00.000000**", obviously UTC+00:00
- CST is six hours behind UTC i.e. UTC−06:00
- Your function `convertTS` will always return the same results irrelevant of the default timezone
- It doesn't matter how many days you subtract, so let's make it simpler and say -2 days

When you call your `convertTS` function it takes the timestamp in UTC and converts and displays it in CST timezone. When you pass 1546578000 as an argument you will get "2019-01-03 23:00:00.000000".

`strtotime` takes in 2 parameters: `int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )`. However PHP documentation says that both parameters of this function use the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. In your example you explicitly give the timezone in the first parameter each time. The second parameter reads the default timestamp and converts the UTC UNIX timestamp into that timezone before the calculation of the relative date.

### Some pseudo code of what is happening

When the timezone is UTC:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
strtotime("-2 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago", 1546578000);
```

1. Convert 1546578000 to **UTC**: `2019-01-04 05:00:00.000000`
2. Set time to 00:00:00 CST: `2019-01-04 06:00:00.000000 *UTC+00:00*`
3. Subtract 2 days: `2019-01-02 06:00:00.000000`
4. Return the timestamp as integer

When the default timezone is CST:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
strtotime("-2 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago", 1546578000);
```

1. Convert 1546578000 to **CST**: `2019-01-03 23:00:00.000000`
2. Set time to 00:00:00 CST: `2019-01-03 06:00:00.000000 *UTC+00:00*`
3. Subtract 2 days: `2019-01-01 06:00:00.000000`
4. Return the timestamp as integer, of course in UTC+00:00, see the first point

PHP parser for relative dates is not perfect. In fact I believe it is wrong when it converts UNIX timestamp to the default timezone... or my understanding of it might also be flawed.

### How I gathered the data:

I changed the code to use `DateTime` class.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

$dt = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(1546578000);
$dt->modify("-2 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");
echo "UTC: ".$dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo "-----------------";
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

///now in America/Chicago
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

$dt = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(1546578000);
$dt->modify("-2 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago");
echo "CST: ".$dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
```

I then used XDebug to debug the code and see what are the internal states of the `$dt` variable.
[image]

And after changing the timezone:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm certainly aware of the first part and how my own function works.  "In fact I believe it is wrong when it converts UNIX timestamp to the default timezone... or my understanding of it might also be flawed."  Yes, that is how I feel.  I feel the timestamp should be converted to the timezone provided IN strtotime NOT the default, then set time to 00:00:00, then subtract the days.  If it behaved that way it would be what I want and expect to happen.  With that said, using your DateTime example I can make this work... just need to figure out the most elegant way to approach it.

Comment: As a matter of best practice you should do all your calculations in UTC. You will avoid most irritating things like this.

Comment: Everything is in UTC in this project, but in this specific case this calculation needs to be done in 'selected' timezone.  'Users' can select their own timezone and this calculation is being used in conjunction with a date/time range selection.

Comment: What does "Unix timestamps are always in UTC" mean exactly? A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since a fixed moment in time (the Unix Epoch), discarding leap seconds.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time - UNIX time by definition is in UTC it is the number of seconds passed since UNIX epoch which is 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970 UTC. This means that the UNIX timestamp in PHP already contains the timezone which is UTC+00:00

Comment: From my understanding, there're two kind of references to UTC in the Wikipedia article: in the definition of Unix Epoch (which can be translated to other time zones and will not alter the value of timestamps) and when mentioning that Unix time is **not** in sync with UTC when it comes to leap seconds (because Unix time predates UTC by two years).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Could you please read the PHP documentation for [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). This should answer most of your question. Take a look also at the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

The time zone in the string is definitively taken into account:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago')));
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 Europe/Madrid')));
```

```
string(31) "Sun, 30 Dec 2018 06:00:00 +0000"
string(31) "Sat, 29 Dec 2018 23:00:00 +0000"
```

Perhaps the confusing part is that the result is **displayed** in the configured time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago')));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago')));
```

```
string(31) "Sun, 30 Dec 2018 06:00:00 +0000"
string(31) "Sun, 30 Dec 2018 07:00:00 +0100"
```

... but the actual moment in time is the same:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago'));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
var_dump(strtotime('-6 days 00:00:00 America/Chicago'));
```

```
string(10) "1546149600"
string(10) "1546149600"
```

Comment: I am not so sure that is the only thing that is confusing. [Try this code example](https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulPristinePi)

Comment: And in that same example if you display the UNIX point in time will also be different.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Dharman pointing out how strtotime actually handles things (which I still think is wrong) I was able to modify a few things and come up with the results I expect regardless of php's default time zone.  This provides the results I expect... where the calculations (subtracting days and setting to 00:00:00) happen in the timezone specified.

[sandbox example](https://repl.it/repls/AromaticChillySolaris)

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

$time = time();
//$time = 1546578000;
$tz = "Europe/Amsterdam";

$dt = new DateTime('@'.$time);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
echo "\n";
echo $dt->format('U');

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

$dt = new DateTime('@'.$time);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->modify("-2 days 00:00:00");
echo $dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
echo "\n";
echo $dt->format('U');

echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "---------------";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";

$dt = new DateTime('@'.$time);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
echo $dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
echo "\n";
echo $dt->format('U');

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

$dt = new DateTime('@'.$time);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));
$dt->modify("-2 days 00:00:00");
echo $dt->format('D, m/d/y @ g:i:s a T');
echo "\n";
echo $dt->format('U');
```

Which in this case would output :

```
Sat, 01/05/19 @ 6:51:18 pm UTC
1546714278

Thu, 01/03/19 @ 12:00:00 am UTC
1546473600

---------------

Sat, 01/05/19 @ 7:51:18 pm CET
1546714278

Thu, 01/03/19 @ 12:00:00 am CET
1546470000
```